# Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super' When using protocols?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-runtime

I have the following structure.
I got `class B` which conforms to `protocol A`.
`protocol A` defines a designated initializer which is`-(instancetype)initWithInt:(int)count`.

However, when I go an implement the standard `-(instancetype)init` in `class B` and make it to use the designated initializer which is also implemented in class B, i am getting the warning "Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super'", while my designated initializer (which IMO is `initWithInt`) never calls any designated initializer on super.

```
@protocol A
{
(instancetype) init;
(instancetype) initWithInt:(NSUInteger)count;
}

@interface B : NSObject <A>

@implementation B
- (instancetype) init {
    return [self initWithInt:0];
}
- (instancetype) initWithInt:(NSUInteger)count {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
```

Any idea why the compiler omits this warning in this specific case?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @matt Just updated the question section.

Comment: How are you going to use this protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html):

> A class interface declares the methods and properties associated with that class. A protocol, by contrast, is used to declare methods and properties that are independent of any specific class.

Each class has its own (inherited) designated initializer. You can't declare a designated initializer in a protocol. If you want to declare an initializer in a protocol, implement it like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithInt:(NSUInteger)count {
    self = [self initWithMyDesignatedInitializer];
    if (self) {
        // do something with count
    }
    return self;
}
```

or like:

```
- (instancetype)initWithInt:(NSUInteger)count {
    return [self initWithMyDesignatedInitializer:count];
}
```

And don't declare `init` in your protocol, it is declared by `NSObject`.

Edit:

It doesn't make sense to declare an initializer in a protocol. When you allocate and initialize the object, you know the class of the object and should call a designated initializer of this class.

Edit 2:

A designated initializer is specific to a class and declared in this class. You can initialize an instance of a class but you can't initialize an instance of a protocol. A protocol makes it possible to talk to an object without knowing the class of this object. Documentation about initializers: [Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3).

Comment: You cannot implement methods in a method in a protocol, not sure I understand what you are talking about here. Besides, rationally speaking, what is wrong with defining a designated initializer in  a protocol, your arguments against it don't provide enough reasoning.

Comment: I think you don't understand what a protocol is. Read [Working with Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Comment: I agree that a protocol is independent of a class. However, whats the reasoning for not allowing a protocol to declare a designated initializer such as initWithInt: , so only classes which implement this initializer can successfully conform to the protocol ? This is the missing part which is still unanswered.

Comment: A designated initializer invokes a designated initializer of its superclass. Other initializers invoke an initializer of self. If my class has a designated initializer `initWithString:`, how would I implement `initWithInt:`? It's missing my string parameter. And how do you allocate an anonymous object and call `initWithInt:`?

Comment: What makes you think that a designated initializer of a class has to call the corresponding designated initializer of it's superclass? IMO it has to call an initializer of it's superclass, not necessarily a designated one.

Comment: Because Apple says so. My answer isn't usefull, I'll remove it.

Comment: That's OK, I think you helped me realize that I cannot do what I wanted to do and that's something too.